# Not able to add anything in the list of type wild card with super keyword

Tags: java, generics

[image]

On the left is the hierarchy of classes. bmws is a list of type anything which is either BMW280 or its super type. in this list ideally i should be able to add BMWS280 and above..
Please let me know what i am missing in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. For `List<Car> vehicles = new ArrayList<Car>();` you could use simple the diamond operator like this `new ArrayList<>();`
2. Your `List<? super BMW280> bmws` means that you will have a list of BMW280 or any typ more specific than BMW280, what means subtypes of BMW280 like `public class BMW290 extends BMW280`.

If you are only pulling items from a generic collection, it is a producer and you should use extends; if you are only stuffing items in, it is a consumer and you should use super. From the name
of your list I assume that you intended to list all kind of BMWs.
You could do this instead:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(new BMW());
        vehicles.add(new BMW240());
        //<? super BMW> if you want to add also new BMW() 
        List<? super BMW240> bmws = vehicles;
        bmws.add(new BMW240());
        bmws.add(new BMW280());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<? super BMWS280> bmws` means **at runtime** bmws will be some specified type either BMWS280 or its super type.
Let's suppose it as type **SpecifiedType**.

###### Let's clarify why `bmws.add(new BMWS280())` works

We don't know what actually the **SpecifiedType** is.But what we can be sure is that BMWS280 (and its sub type) must be the sub type of the SpecifiedType,so you can add it to the bmws.

###### Let's clarify why `bmws.add(new BMWS240())` not works

Since **SpecifiedType** is either BMWS280 or its super type,it's not safe to add any instance which type is greater than BMWS280.

For example : what if the **SpecifiedType** is BMWS280, obviously `bmws.add(new BMWS240())` is not a type safe code.